# Creating a twitter chatbot

Tags: twitter, chatbot, openweathermap

I am just a beginner for python and raspberry. I am trying to build a twitter bot to fetch real-time weather from 'openweathermap.org' and tweet it using a bot. Can anyone suggest me a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made little research or effort to solve your problem. But anyway...

There are 3 key things here:

- Retrieve weather data
- Push data to Twitter
- Automate the whole thing

For the first two there are plenty of solutions out there. For the automation, you just can make a cron job, just search for cronjob on the internet.